# Joomla- BlogLayout: Show title and image of sub category

Tags: joomla

I have a menu item that shows articles from a category and two sub-categories on a website as blog layout.
Now I want to achieve that I just want to display the title and image of all sub categories, but not of the parent category.

I guess I have to override the standard views in components\com_content\views\category\tmpl but I don't know how I could do that.

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks,

enne

Comment: Which version of Joomla?

Comment: Sry, forgot to mention: Joomla 3.1

Comment: I even don't know how to show the subcategory title. Isn't there any switch in the backend?

Comment: Does reading [this article](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla) help? I think that you can get what you want by creating an alternative menu item. If you have any specific question, feel free to post it.

Comment: Hi MasterAM, that helps very much, thank you for your response!